# Help finding coordinate for left of screen in this frustum

Tags: opengl

I have a frustum with `l=-2`, `r=2`, `n=0.5`, `f=10`, corresponding to left, right, near, far respectively. I also define top and bottom too.

I've set the camera eye up at `(0, 0, -2.5)`, looking directly at `(0, 0, 0)` with up `(0, 1, 0)`.

Suppose I want to position an object centred at `z=-1`. I want to find the `x` coordinate so that under this frustum it appears exactly centred on the left edge of the screen.

I set up the following diagram to help me:

```
                       +z
                       |
            \          |          /
     -x<_____\_________|_________/______>x
              \____x___|-1      /
               \       |       /
                \      |      /
                 \_|l|_|     /
                  \    |    /     |near dist=n=0.5
                   \   |   /      |
                    \  |  /       |
                     \a| /        |
                      \|/         |
                       |-2.5
                       |
                       -z
```

So to find `x` I can use simple trig. Since `tan a = |l|/n` and `tan a=x/1.5` then the formula for `x` is `x=|l|/n*1.5=2/0.5*1.5=6`, where `|.|` is the absolute value.

But when I use this `x` value to draw an object left of the centre, it does not appear centred at the edge of the screen. I can see the object but it's not on the edge. Moreover, if I increase `n` then the gap between the object and the left edge increases. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Empirically I have discovered that if I compute `x=|l|/n*2.5` then my object is correctly centred on the left edge of the device screen, and works for any `n` value I choose. Not sure why 2.5 works...

**SOLUTION**

Not really worthy of an answer, but I found in some legacy code that the renderer was set up to transalte the z forward by 1 unit, so this was undoing my `-1` z value, hence why multiplying by 2.5 worked and not 1.5.

Despite this annoying fact, I'm now confident I fully understand how the frustum fits into OpenGL.

Comment: In your text you write "exactly centered on the left edge" and in the drawing you show it centered in the left *half* of the screen.

Comment: @Bram well, the camera is centred at `(0,0,0)` so `(-x,0,0)` should be exactly on the left edge of the screen. As you can see the left side of the frustum skims the left of the near plane so `x` should correspond to the left edge of the screen for `z=-1`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example:

```
0.5*left / n = x / 1.5
-1 / 0.5 = x / 1.5
-2 = x / 1.5
-3 = x
```

Or more elaborately, if you want to go via the angle it self:

```
tan( a ) = 0.5*left / 0.5
a = atan( -2 )
tan( a ) = x / 1.5
tan( atan( -2 ) ) = x / 1.5
-2 = x / 1.5
-3 = x
```

Comment: But `tan a` is not equal to `0.5*left/0.5` ... it is equal to `l/n`... goimg by `tan = opposite / adjacent`

Comment: Maybe the drawing was a little confusing, please see update. Nonetheless the `x` value does not draw at the exact left edge of the screen. I'm sure my maths is right? So there must be some unkown i dont know about. Will take a look again.